# How to get a ui.Thumbnail with a standard Google Maps type as background

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-maps, export, thumbnail

within the Google Earth Engine (Javascript API) I would like to create a Thumbnail image with a standard Google Maps type, (e.g. Terrain style) as background. The thumbnail image is set to be opaque (0.5). However, I can't figure out how to add the google base layer.

Here is the ui.Thumbnail GEE Developer example:

```
// Create a box around an area in the Brazilian Amazon.
var box = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
  [-62.9564, 2.5596], [-62.9550, 2.4313],
  [-62.8294, 2.4327], [-62.8294, 2.5596]
]]);

// Visualize the image in RGB.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR/LE07_233058_20011113').visualize({
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1200,
  gamma: [1.3, 1.3, 1]
});

// Print a thumbnail to the console.
print(ui.Thumbnail({
  image: image,
  params: {
    dimensions: '256x256',
    region: box,
    format: 'png'
  },
  style: {height: '300px', width: '300px'}
}));
```

The thumbnail so far, but without the desired background map.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

- The Google Maps base layer is provided within the Earth Engine Code Editor and Earth Engine Apps for interactive use only.
- The Google Earth Engine API cannot be used to download portions of the Google Maps base layer, only images computed within Earth Engine (using images from the Earth Engine Data Catalog).